# Output of 'cat' to a a file in Node.js

Tags: node.js, cat

i am trying to do something simple (in a much larger context) with Node.js . Basically doing this :

```
cat file1.avi file2.avi file3.avi > final_file.avi
```

I tried this :

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,
    cat = spawn("cat", ["file1.avi","file2.avi", "file3.avi", ">", "final_file.avi"]);

cat.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

cat.stderr.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

But it does not work, it just outputs the 'cat' to the stdout and not into 'final_file'. 
[Edit] Important to note they are AVI files

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 6):

The `>` redirection symbol is a feature of your shell, not of the operating system or of `cat`. When you called `cat` with > as an argument it is passed as an argument If you want to save the contents of those files do it inside of the on("data") function

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

cat = spawn('cat',["file1.avi", "file2.avi"]);    
cat.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log(data); 
});
```

Comment: Indeed, should've thought about that

Comment: Hi, while this works for text files, it does not seem to work for Avi files (should've specified in the question, my bad).

Comment: Yes, it is supported by AVI format, from the ffmpeg documentation: http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-join-video-files_003f

Answer (score 3):

Cat just pipes stdin to stdout.  The Node.js file system module can do the same.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var inputs = ["file1.avi","file2.avi", "file3.avi"];
var output = fs.createWriteStream("final_file.avi");

function pipe () {
  var input = fs.createReadStream( inputs.shift() );
  output.pipe(input);
  input.on('end', function () {
    if(inputs.length) {
      pipe();
    }
  });
}
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

The > redirection symbol is a feature of your shell. you can enable shell feature eg.

`const cmd = spawn("cat", ["file1.avi", ">", "final_file.avi"],{ shell: true });`